# how to upload 900MB csv file from a website to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv

I want to do some data analysis from NYCopendata. The file is ~900 MB. So I am using postgresql database to store this file. I am using pgadmin4 but could not figure out how to directly store the csv in postgresl without first downloading in my machine. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `copy yourtable from program 'curl https://url.of.the/file'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1. pgAdmin to upload a CSV file from import/export dialog
   https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.21/import_export_data.html
2. COPY statement on the database server
3. \copy command from psql on any client

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but somehow my import/export option is disabled in pgadmin4